# How to upload third party libraries in Nexus NPM Repository?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, nexus

I have created node application and in my application I am using some third party libraries say for example Express. It all works well without any issues if I install it from https://registry.npmjs.org.

But because of some security reason I don't want to download it from npm registery, Instead I want that it should be downloaded from my private repository ( We are using Nexus OSS as private repository ).

The problem is I am not able to find way to upload Express module in Nexus Registery. I found one way using Npm proxy but for security reasons we can not use it.

Do any one know how to upload third party libraries to Nexus npm Registry?

Comment: What error are you seeing that prevents you from uploading to NXRM?